# Different screensize and language in android

Tags: android, android-layout, localization

I want to support different screen sizes and languages at the same time. So I got some folders for my layout like

- layout (German)
- layout-en (English)
- layout-fr (French)

etc...

and I got layout-large for big screens. So when I open another language in the large screen I got the layout from the small screen. Is there a way to manage this? layout-large-fr or layout-fr-large did not work...

And of course I defined translated strings.

Comment: The layouts are not depending on the language and if they are in your app you might want to change that. In order to support several languages you need to use localized strings and images, but not layouts.

Comment: Well i use localized strings, but they do not have the same lenghts so  they f**k up my layout... and it is possible to differ with those layout options I mentioned above... But they only work for the small/regular layouts...

Comment: What do you mean by "they do not have same lengths"? Your way is wrong.

Comment: He probably say that for example "Hello" has 4 characters in English, but in Chinese it has only one character -> so the length is different

Comment: user42949 thats exactly my point!

Comment: You should create a layout that fit's all languages. Especially english, german and french aren't that different in length. Use a smaller font ;). singleLine="true" may help and use ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Create on layout file for each language. Create on layout.xml in res/values-xx with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <item name="main_layout" type="layout">@layout/activity_main_xx</item>

</resources>
```

The result should looks like this:

[image]

Comment: and in you activity you load the main_layout -> setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);